# Scraping next pages issue with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape basic information on google. The code that I am using is the following. Unfortunately it does not move to the next page and I am not figuring the reason why. I am using selenium and google chrome as browser (no firefox). Could you please tell me what is wrong in my code?

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com/advanced_search?q=google&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:3/4/2020,cd_max:3/4/2020&hl=en')

search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('tea')
search.submit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
result_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'g'})

titles = []

while True:
    next_page_btn =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']")
    for r in result_div:
        if len(next_page_btn) <1:
            print("no more pages left")
            break
        else:
            try:
                title = None
                title = r.find('h3')

                if isinstance(title,Tag):
                    title = title.get_text()
                    print(title)
                if title != '' :
                    titles.append(title)
            except:
                continue

        element =WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'pnnext')))
        driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        element.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set q in the query string to be an empty string. Used `as_q` not `q` for the search box name. And reordered your code a bit. I put a page limit in to stop it going on forever.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/advanced_search?q=&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:3/4/2020,cd_max:3/4/2020&hl=en')

search = driver.find_element_by_name('as_q')
search.send_keys('tea')
search.submit()

titles = []
page_limit = 5
page = 0

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    result_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'g'})
    for r in result_div:
        for title in r.find_all('h3'):
            title = title.get_text()
            print(title)
            titles.append(title)
    next_page_btn = driver.find_elements_by_id('pnnext')
    if len(next_page_btn) == 0 or page > page_limit:
        break
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'pnnext')))
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    element.click()
    page = page + 1
driver.quit()
```