# Scraping loop on list with next page using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, list-comprehension

[Scraping next pages issue with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876418/scraping-next-pages-issue-with-selenium)

is somewhat similar althogh i dont want to make it more complicated by using with bs4

I want to scrape all 10 titles (links to pdfs) on every page. Here is the code that throws a StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (at `i.click()`)

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[class="btn btn-primary"][type="submit"]').click()    
    
for j in range(10):
    pdfs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".title a")
    if j < 10:
        nextpg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".tx-pagebrowse-page button")
        pdfs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".title a")
    for i in pdfs:
        i.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    if j < 10:
        nextpg.click()
    else:
        break
```

below it shows that the first page is a `type=list` list with the right titles

```
pdfs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".title a")
print(type(pdfs))
for my_pdf in pdfs:
    print(my_pdf.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

<class 'list'>
                                dfhgadr asfdgsd
                                sDF SDF 
                                SDFSDF sdf
                                SDF DSfdf
                                SDFD sdf
                                SDFSdf fdf
                                zewr4
                                sHSDFG 
                                RSZJRT
                                dhff fgf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pdfs[[i]].click() You may try as follows:

```
 i.click()
```

Comment: Hi. ´AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'click'´

Comment: Try  to use as: str(i).click()

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: Instead of  clic() ,  try to use Send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'Send_keys'

Comment: You may try a little bit change in for loop: for i in pdfs:

Comment: that worked somewhat, thank you. It opened a pdf and then threw

AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'WebDriverWait'

Comment: Because  sleep and  WebDriverWait mixed are not allowed but you main problem has solved.Thanks

Comment: I figured that out, thanks. Now it thows this: StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document. At `i.click()`

Comment: Because element may remove from DOM.Please take help fron here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225997/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document